# how to prevent postback using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Div_1").show();
    $("#Div_2").hide();

    $('#Buttion1').click(function () {
        $("#Div_1").hide();
        $("#Div_2").show();
    });
});
```

in the above code, while loading is working but when click (Buttion1 is ASP.Net Server button)  on button Div_2 not showing off and Div_1 not hiding off

Comment: Do you have server code for Buttion1 click event handler?

Comment: yes i have server code

Comment: tell me proper solution

Comment: Is Button1 placed in UpdatePanel?

Comment: not inside update panel

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#Buttion1').click(function () {

        $("#Div_1").hide();
        $("#Div_2").show();
                 return false;
```

});

Comment: i have server code for Buttion1 click event handler! thats not firing

Comment: this code prevents postback using jquery, that was the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way to do it.

Eg: http://jsfiddle.net/vtLMT/

HTML

```
<div id="div1">Div1</div>
<div id="div2">Div2</div>
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

CSS

```
#div1 {  }
#div2 { display: none; }
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").show();
    return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: i have server code for Buttion1 click event handler! thats not firing

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Div_1").show();
        $("#Div_2").hide();

        $('#Buttion1').click(function () {
            $("#Div_1").hide();
            $("#Div_2").show();
            return false;
        });

    });
```

or

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button Text="text" ID="Buttion1" OnClientClick="hideshow();" runat="server"
            OnClick="Buttion1_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Buttion1" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<div id="Div_1">
</div>
<div id="Div_2">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Div_1").show();
            $("#Div_2").hide();
        });

    })
    function hideshow() {
        $("#Div_1").hide();
        $("#Div_2").show();
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

server side code

```
    protected void Buttion1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
        //server side code
    }
```

note:

1)your two div must be out side updatepanel.

2)your hideshow function must not be undefined.Place function on at the en of the page

3)on button client click call hideshow function which return true

4) after javascript function return true..it goes for the server side event

Comment: according above code    function hideshow() {
        $("#Div_1").hide();
        $("#Div_2").show();
        return true;
    } hideshow() method not working

Comment: put the function at last of page

Comment: i did it, even not working hideshow() method, we are very near to solution. try it

Comment: i have append note in my answer