# Asp.net Button event fire with jquery code

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Div_1").show();
    $("#Div_2").hide();

    $('#Button1').click(function () {

        $("#Div_1").hide();
        $("#Div_2").show();
        return false;
    });

});
```

in the above code jquery code is working fine but event is not firing

Comment: which event ? Server side / client side ? can you please elaborate on your requirement and issue being faced ?

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {

$("#Div_1").show();
$("#Div_2").hide();

$('#Button1').click(function () {

    $("#Div_1").hide();
    $("#Div_2").show();
    return false;
});


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            Label1.Text = "Hello";
} Exact code

Comment: so you want to say that the server side event does not get fired, right ?

Comment: Better add the code to your post instead of writing code here.

Comment: So the jQuery click handler is not being executed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to prevent postback using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231249/how-to-prevent-postback-using-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

In your JavaScript code you attach a client-side click handler to the button and then `return false` at the end of the handler.  This prevents the click event from continuing up the DOM, which is also probably causing it to not fire the built-in post-back code.

Try removing the `return false` statement in order to fire the post-back to the server.

Be aware, however, that this might not behave as you expect.  Whatever you're doing client-side (showing/hiding elements it would appear) will only happen for a brief instant before the code posts to the server and the page refreshes, losing those client-side changes.

Comment: Question is duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231249/how-to-prevent-postback-using-jquery/17231303#17231303

Comment: @RajeshGonugunta: Depends on what you want to do, which isn't at all clear from the sample code.  If you have to post back to the server *and* you have to show/hide elements on the page then you should show/hide them in server-side code.  If you don't have to post back to the server and can handle the click event entirely on the client (or with maybe an AJAX post to the server) then you can use a plain HTML button (no server-side control) and control the event client-side.

Comment: @cinek: Interesting.  It's an edge case for duplication, since he's asking two different questions which happen to be two different sides of the same issue.  That issue being a fundamental misunderstanding of how web development works regarding client-side and server-side functionality...